# What is right age for children to start fasting?

Tags: sawm, ramadan, children

In the month of Ramadan everyone would fast seeing which children are tempted to fast. So can anyone put some light on this question of mine that when is the right age for children to start fasting?

Comment: Right age, from a medical or Islamic perspective? Or any other?

Comment: according to Islamic way

Comment: Well if it comes to at what age one should start fasting then from the time one reaches adolescence on one has to fast as it would be fard/farz. But the right age a child should experience fasting is really depending on the child, it's health, culture, customs etc.

Answer (score 2):

A person should start fasting when they reach puberty. 
According to modern science and Islam, there are 3 sign of puberty you can look for, and if either of them appears first, then the person has reached puberty and should fast. 
The conditions are,

1. Growth of pubic hair on the private parts.
2. Age of 15.
3. Ejaculation in males and menstrual cycle is females.

If either of them appears first, then you can conclude the person has reached puberty and should fast. 
Hope this helps.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer. But of course, one can start fasting way before that if they wish :)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this](http://islamqa.info/en/65558) link:

Every child should start fasting when they reach the age of adolescence.

Answer (score -1):

Although it is seen that apparently there are some (or much) differences between different sects of Sunnis and even Shia regarding the age of the puberty, but I assume all of them or at least more of them believe that children should be fast since the start of puberty aging. In regard to the age of the puberty, as a general rule from the viewpoint of Shiite, it is 9 for the girls and 15 for the boys. (Although it can be related to the signs of the puberty as well to change its age...)

Answer (score -1):

The answer of the question is obvious that it depends on the age of Buloogh (adolescence). Because once a person reaches the age of adolescence, the wajib practices will be mandatory for him or her. and whereas fasting is one of those wajib practices, thus an adult (baaliq) person should do his or her wajib practices among fasting.